# Why does powershell comparison code block not work when put into function?

Tags: powershell

Trying to understand why the following code block returns different results.

```
$item1 = "bill"
$item2 = "bill"

# This returns "Values are the same"
if ($item1 -eq $item2) {
    echo "Values are the same"
}
else {
    echo "Values are NOT the same"
}

# This returns "Values are NOT same"
function compare_items($i1, $i2)
{
    if ($i1 -eq $i2) {
        echo "Values are the same"
    }
    else {
        echo "Values are NOT the same"
    }
}

compare_items($item1, $item2)
```

I would think both return the same result as values being the same. I've tried type casting the variables as [string] and still getting same mismatch of results.

Comment: You are passing the arguments incorrectly. You don't need parenthesis and the arguments should be space delimited. See the linked duplicate. Should be `compare_items $item1 $item2`

Comment: "set-strictmode -version latest" would catch this.  "The function or command was called as if it were a method. Parameters should be separated by spaces."  It's a common point of confusion.